# Is it possible to open multiple bluetooth sockets to a single device with Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, bluetooth

I'm writing an MPD controller app for Android and I was wondering if it's possible to maintain multiple connections to a single device. Essentially I want the server on my PC to spawn three threads and have the phone connect to each of the of them. I've tried this using different `UUID`s for each thread but the phone only ever connects to the first one.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible. A Bluetooth device is capable of connecting to multiple devices at a time so it easily comes to mind to use multiple connections to a single device. But each device (means each bluetooth adapter) has a MAC-Address like Ethernet devices do identifying it. This means if a device is already connected to another device you can not connect them again unless one of them changes the MAC address. The only way to connect the two devices twice is to add a second bluetooth adapter to one of them but this won't give you much more additional bandwith (in my opinion).

Hope this was kinda helpful!

Comment: Yep, that's the conclusion I ended up coming to as well unfortunately.